# Apache mod_proxy content-length vs chunked encoding

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I have apache configured to proxy for a (old, creaky, and basically http 1.0) web server that does not deliver a content-length header, just relying on closing the connection to mark end of data.

Under apache 2.2, mod_proxy handled this by using Transfer-Encoding: chunked, and then delivering the data as fast as the remote server would deliver the data. Under apache 2.4, mod_proxy handles this by waiting for the entire response from the remote server, then delivers the page with a content-length. As the backend server could potentially take 30+ seconds to gradually fill a page of results, the older behavior is preferable. There is no obvious configuration change that would have resulted in this behavior; I've tried out proxy-sendchunked but it doesn't seem to help (as described, it relates to data being uploaded by POST requests, which isn't the issue here).

Is this configurable and I've just missed it?